# Why System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames() produces a DirectoryNotFoundException?

Tags: c#

Just one line:

```
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

It works well when debugging, but the published version will produce a DirectoryNotFoundException:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\dev'.
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.CreateDirectoryHandle(String path, Boolean ignoreNotFound)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.Init()
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1..ctor(String directory, Boolean isNormalized, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1..ctor(String directory, FindTransform transform, EnumerationOptions options, Boolean isNormalized)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.UserFiles(String directory, String expression, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalEnumeratePaths(String path, String searchPattern, SearchTarget searchTarget, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
   at ...
```

When runing somewhere in disk D, it will try finding `D:\dev` instead of `C:\dev`.

Creating the directory can make it work, but why it requires such a directory?

Comment: Works for me. Which .net framework/version are you using?

Comment: Have you looked at the source code for it? https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/sys/system/IO/ports/SerialPort.cs#L670 I would look here in your registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM`, because that's all it does that i can see. Chances are there is a problem with your specific machine.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're somehow invoking a code path for Linux (which would look for device files named `/dev/ttyS*`) when you're running on Windows. You should provide more details on your environment: framework version, build process, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. After I updated the nuget package (System.IO.Ports), the problem seems to no longer exist.

I haven't found out why, and although I tried changing its version back, the exception isn't reproduced either.